# Виртуальный массив

Tags: c++, массивы

Допустим есть два обычных одномерных массива и есть функция принимающая один массив. Необходимо объединить эти два массива в один и передать его в функцию. Как объединить массивы классическим способом я знаю. Но на выделение дополнительной памяти для третьего массива и копирование внутрь него двух других массивов очень дорогостоящая операция. Меня интересует существует ли структура которая позволяет виртуально объединить несколько массивов в один на уровне индексации памяти и имеет свойства обычного массива? Вот пример:

```
#include <iostream>

void print(int c[6]){
     for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        std::cout << c[i];
}

int main(){
  int a[3] = { 1, 2, 3 };
  int b[3] = { 4, 5, 6 };

  // здесь создать виртуальный массив из индексов памяти массивов a и b
  print(/* и передать его сюда */);
}
```

Comment: Нет, такой возможности нет. Либо вам придется переопределять функцию, либо создавать один массив из других массивов.

Comment: Вы в любом случае будете расходовать память.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow , а `union` в этом деле использовать не получится? как нибудь так http://cpp.sh/3finy ?

Comment: интересно, как спасет его union в данной ситуации :-/

Comment: @Sublihim у union внутри общая память

Comment: @perfect это-то да, вы только представьте, что там будет для 3-х массивов?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вам в любом случае придется переопределять функцию, либо создавать новый массив из имеющихся массивов.

Один из подходов может состоять в определении функции, которая принимает список инициализации. Например,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <utility>

void print(std::initializer_list<std::pair<const int *, size_t>> arrays)
{
    for ( const auto &p : arrays )
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < p.second; i++)
        {
            std::cout << p.first[i] << ' ';
        }
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    int a[3] = { 1, 2, 3 };
    int b[3] = { 4, 5, 6 };

    print({ { a, 3 }, { b, 3 } });
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль будет

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Вы эту функцию можете объявить одновременно вместе с перегруженной функцией

```
void print( const int *a, size_t n );
```

Comment: эх жаль. мне обычный массив хотелось бы получить..

Comment: ну в порядке извращения можно создать свой класс, который будет реализовывать поведение массива, но хранить внутри себя 2 (а можно и больше) массивов и вести себя как будто они склеены.

Comment: @pavel .. и в классе использовать тот же initializer_list ? если да то смысла в этом не вижу

Answer (score 0):

Для этой цели хорошо сгодится библиотека Ranges, которая умеет делать "ленивые" вычисления. В будущем предполагается добавить её в стандарт языка C++.

> Меня интересует существует ли структура которая позволяет виртуально объединить несколько массивов в один на уровне индексации памяти и имеет свойства обычного массива?

Именно это она и умеет делать. Буквально на днях мелькала статья практически с Вашим примером (ленивая конкатенация строк) - [Идиома Ranges](https://habrahabr.ru/post/318266/)

Ссылка на библиотеку - [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3)

---

Попытка написать рабочий код при помощи этой библиотеки:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <range/v3/view/concat.hpp>

template <class Range>
void print(Range c){
    for (auto elem : c)
        std::cout << elem;
}

int main(){
    int a[3] = { 1, 2, 3 };
    int b[3] = { 4, 5, 6 };

    auto c = ranges::v3::view::concat(a, b);
    print(c);
}
```

P.S. Не уверен, умеет ли `concat` работать с чистыми массивами.